# passing component variables to controller in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, controller, components

how do I pass a variable declared in a function in a cakePHP component to a controller? I can't seem to work this out.

Comment: Do you have some code you could post?

Comment: No explanation on what is required, what you have, what you would like it to do... Bad question. Bad bad bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it a number of ways.  Basically, you just call the component's functions that you need from the controller and return values:

```
//In controller
$alteredData = $this->MyComponent->doSomethingWithData($data);

//In component
//You can also pass $data by reference if you want to alter it directly.
public function doSomethingWithData($data){
    //alter data in some way
    return $newData;
}
```

[Per the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html?highlight=component#Component), you also have direct access to the controller from the component so you can call controller methods from the component.

```
//In component
private $Controller;
public function initialize($controller){
    $this->Controller = $controller;
}

public function doSomethingWithData($data){
    //alter data in some way
    $this->Controller->set('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: make sure to load component like : *public $components = array('MyComponent');*  otherwise  *$this->Controller->set('data', $data);* wiil not work

Comment: Are there any updated on how to do this in cakephp 3.x

Answer (score 0):

in cakePHP 3.x (maybe only > 3.5)

```
// in Component
$this->getController()->set('var', $var);
```